# Can I accept more than one answer for my question?

Tags: feature-request

I have asked many questions in  English Language Learners, and sometimes I noticed that there was more than one answer that I liked. I wanted to accept them all, but I couldn't see how to do this.

Can I accept more than one answer for a question I asked?

Comment: This page in the help center has some good information: http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. You can only accept one answer, but you can up-vote as many as you like.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, ColleenV!

Answer (score 0):

No, you may not accept more than one answer. The idea behind it is that you are supposed to choose the "best" answer. This page has some good info https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers